# Cannot use parse-rest API

Tags: rest, django-models

I cannot use package parse-rest.

Module parse_rest.connection is not found. 
I installed it using pip install parse-rest. 
Could you tell me what is missing, please!!!
looking at H:\py_env\ where is my virtualenv installed it does not exists.

```
ImportError at /
No module named parse_rest.connection
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    local
Django Version: 1.7.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named parse_rest.connection
Exception Location: H:\py_env\src\propiedades\models.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['H:\\py_env\\src', ...]

********************************************

    (py_env) H:\py_env>pip install parse_rest
      Downloading/unpacking parse-rest
      Downloading parse_rest-0.10.2013.tar.gz
      Running setup.py (path:H:\py_env\build\parse-rest\setup.py) egg_info for package parse-rest

    Installing collected packages: parse-rest
      Running setup.py install for parse-rest

    Successfully installed parse-rest
    Cleaning up...

    (py_env) H:\py_env>pip freeze
    Django==1.7.1
    parse-rest==0.10.2013

    (py_env) H:\py_env>pip show --files parse_rest

    (py_env) H:\py_env>pip show --files parse-rest
    ---
    Name: parse-rest
    Version: 0.10.2013
    Location: h:\py_env\lib\site-packages
    Requires:
    Files:
        ..\parse_rest\installation.py
        ..\parse_rest\query.py
        ..\parse_rest\settings_local.py
        ..\parse_rest\tests.py
        ..\parse_rest\__init__.py
        ..\parse_rest\installation.pyc
        ..\parse_rest\query.pyc
        ..\parse_rest\settings_local.pyc
        ..\parse_rest\tests.pyc
        ..\parse_rest\__init__.pyc
        .\
        dependency_links.txt
        PKG-INFO
        SOURCES.txt
        top_level.txt

    (py_env) H:\py_env>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running "manage.py runserver" instead of "python manage.py runsever" and it run the default Python located in c:\ file, not in the virtualenv.